# Almost free modules, PCF theory bound on $2^{\aleph_\omega}$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Why [here](https://books.google.COM/books?id=4ei5WzgnnM4C&pg=PA181&printsec=frontcover) (*Almost Free Modules: Set-theoretic Methods by* P.C. Eklof, A.H. Mekler), on the page 181, in the 3rd line there is
$$2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_2}$$? How the index $2$ in the r.h.s. was created?

> The notation "pcf" stands for possible cofinality. Shelahintroduced a powerful tool into the study of cardinal arithmetic when he considered (for an infinite set $A$ of regular cardinals) the set $\operatorname{pcf}(A)$, defined to be the set of all cardinals $\lambda$ such that for some ultrafilter $U$ on $A$, $\lambda$ is the cofinality of the ultraproduct of ordered sets $\prod_{\kappa\in A} \kappa/U$. Among the striking results he proved (in ZFC) are: if $2^{\aleph_n}<\aleph_\omega$ for all $n\in\omega$ then $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\min\{\aleph_{(2^{\aleph_0})^+},\aleph_{\omega_4}\}$; in particular, if GCH holds below $\aleph_\omega$, then $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_2}$. (See Shelah 1992, Shelah 1994 or Jech 1995 or Burke-Magidor 1990.)

[image: page 180]

[image: page 181]

Comment: could someone tell me what $\omega_2$ is supposed to mean?
I've never seen this notation before.

Comment: @PinkPanther: It is the second uncountable cardinal, or the third infinite cardinal.

Comment: I don't understand the question; the text you quoted gives the reason for the bound and provides references for the proof. It is a combination of two results of Shelah. One first appeared in the first edition of his "Proper forcing" book (it is not in the revised edition), and the other is in his "Cardinal arithmetic" book.

Comment: OK then. I just wondered if $2$ should be read as $4$, but you say that "no".

Comment: Yes, in fact you do not need the results from "Cardinal arithmetic", just the earlier result in the Proper forcing book.

Comment: Could you please possibly give me the page number before the question is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\aleph_{\omega_2}$ arises because under the assumption of GCH below $\aleph_\omega$, we have:

$$(2^{\aleph_0})^+ = \aleph_1^+ = \omega_2$$

so that the minimum $\min\{\aleph_{(2^{\aleph_0})^+},\aleph_{\omega_4}\}$ is actually not $\aleph_{\omega_4}$, but the other argument, which evaluates to $\aleph_{\omega_2}$.